# How can one orthogonalize the pointwise sum of two orthogonal sets?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices, linear-independence

Let $n = 2k$, and suppose that $V = \{v_1, \cdots, v_k\}$ is an orthogonal set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. In other words, the vectors in set $V$ are pairwise orthogonal to each other.

Now, consider a new set $W = \{v_1 + e_1, \cdots, v_k + e_k\}$. Here, each $e_j$ represents the standard vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose non-zero component is located in the $j^{th}$ position and equals $1$.

There are well-known processes for orthogonalizing $W$ in the literature. Due to dealing with a specific situation, is it possible to propose a process where, in this particular case, an explicit formula for the vectors after orthogonalization can be provided to us?"